# Can I not load a given mapped property (nhibernate)?

Tags: wcf, nhibernate, limit

I am using WCF for my project and i need to transit some entities through it.

The thing is that some of them have lists inside, with an enormeous ammount of items, and so forth, i cannot pass it through WCF, given its size.

How can I, through code, not load a given property from the database, but load all the rest?

Comment: Are you certain that size is the reason you can't transmit the lists? I've seen others have trouble with nHibernate because it uses the `IList<T>` interface for lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually due to sirrocco I've endured myself.
I a friend of mine helped me to finding this:

[http://www.junasoftware.com/blog/nhibernate-setresulttransformer-and-dto.aspx](http://blog.hibernate.org/Bloggers/Everyone/Year/2006/Month/03/Day/17)

Answer (score 1):

By default the NH lists are lazy loaded - so unless you specified otherwise, the list will not be loaded.

However , the property will be an IProxy..something that won't be serializable. If you want you can probably set an [XmlIgnore] or [NotSerializable] (not sure how it's sent over wcf) on that specific property.

Having said that - do prefer using a DTO instead of sending your entity over the wire. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190718/how-do-i-serialize-all-properties-of-an-nhibernate-mapped-object/1191871#1191871) for more about why you shouldn't send the entity.

Comment: I was going to give up... but you know what? I am gonna deal with their shenanigans! Even if it kills me!