# Fluent-nHibernate using results

Tags: c#, serialization, fluent-nhibernate

To receive entities from database I created the class with virtual members.
When I received an entity from database I cant serialize it and I can't send it by web service.
Is there any any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Please post some sample code here

Comment: I found that post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190718/how-do-i-serialize-all-properties-of-an-nhibernate-mapped-object it's like my situation

Answer (score 0):

Do your typical setup...

```
public class MyTable
{
    public virtual int ID {get;set;}
    public virtual string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I have a special response class I wrap my data in when responding to a web service call

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
... 

[XmlInclude(typeof(Response))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(MyTable))]
public class Response
{
    public virtual bool Success {get;set;}
    public virtual MyTable MyTable {get;set;}
}
```

The "[XmlInclude(typeof(Response))]" and "[XmlInclude(typeof(MyTable))]" causes the table "MyTable" to serialize as XML within "Response".  If you reference "MyTable" as a list you will need "[XmlInclude(typeof(List))]".

I hope this helps put you on the right track.  I had a hard time with the same thing until I found something similar to this.